# Best practices to document user flow for your portfolio

Tags: user-behavior, portfolio, analytics

As a UX contractor, much of my work is under non disclosure agreements. In order to document and present user flows in my portfolio, what's the best way to show examples without risking confidential information?

Comment: Either ask for a written consent, or create such diagrams as part of an non-commissioned (so either do some work on your spare time, possibly related to a famous site, or pick an open source project).

Comment: Alternatively, you can white-label the work. Just run it by the client first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the flows themselves are patented, you should be able to generalize everything by stripping out all the client's information to add to your portfolio.  Wireframes and such should be allowed at the very least.

Once you have that done it is best to confirm with the client that what you are posting to the public is acceptable. At times they may request that you don't make it available publically (on a website) but you are ok to submit it as references to your work upon demand.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- ask your NDA'd clients if there is anything you *could* show. They may be fine in the context of a portfolio.
- add to your contracts the right to reproduce client work (within reason) in your personal portfolio
- obfuscate the work you do under NDA (Use 'Corporation, Inc.' as the logo, 'widget' and 'sprocket' as product names, etc.)
- show the work anyways (which actually isn't that uncommon. I wouldn't publish it online, but passing it around during a job interview is usually OK--but, of course, use your judgement and decide on a case-by-case basis)